# Jetpack Compose setup issue: Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile'

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a new Android project and I want to make use of Jetpack Compose, but following the steps [outlined here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) gives me the following build error:

```
Unable to load class 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile'.

This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file.
```

Perhaps I'm compounding the issue by using Kotlin DSL build.gradle.kts, but here's my gradle setup:

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
    id("kotlin-kapt")
    id("dagger.hilt.android.plugin")
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion(30)

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "..."
        minSdkVersion(24)
        targetSdkVersion(30)
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        getByName("release") {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro")
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
        targetCompatibility(JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8)
    }

    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding = true
        compose = true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        useIR = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion = "1.4.20"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.0.0-alpha08"
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(fileTree(mapOf("dir" to "libs", "include" to listOf("*.jar"))))
    //...

}
```

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Try '1.0.0-alpha09'and Kotlin version "1.4.21" and you should be good to go.

Have you got this in your buildscript?

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        compose_version = '1.0.0-alpha09'
    }
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.21"
```